# Smooth quartic surface in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ that contains a smooth curve of genus 2 and degree 6.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, intersection-theory

I am reading through an article by Matsumura and Monsky on [Automorphisms of Hypersurfaces](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kjm/1250524785) in which they state that there exist quartic surfaces is $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ which have infinite automorphism groups, this is Theorem 4 in the linked article.

They construct an example of such a surface but it is not explicit, they say;

*"Let $F$ be a non-singular (smooth) quartic surface in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ containing a non-singular curve $C$ of genus 2 and of degree 6."*

I was wondering if there was an explicit formula for such a surface?

I have read around and found that a possible construction of a non-singular qaurtic surface in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ is to take the intersection of 2 quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^{4}$, and also a construction of a non-singular curve of genus 2 and degree 6 is to take a polynomial $f(x)$ in one variable with 6 distinct roots and then consider the hyper-elliptic curve $y^{2}=f(x)$. However I do not know how to combine these two constructions together to give the surface I am looking for.

Finally they say that the result is classical and cite 3 articles claiming they contain other examples/constructions, one due to G. Fano (*Sopra alcune superficie del 4 ordine rappresentabili sal piano doppio (1906)*), and two due to F. Severi (*Complementi alla teoria della base per la totalita delle curve di una superficie algebric (1910)*, and *Geometria dei sistemi algebrici (1958)*) all of which are very old and also in Italian. I cannot get a hold of any of the three articles (nor can I read Italian), so these do not provide much help.

Any help about a possible construction or a pointer to an article that isn't in Italian would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "I have read around and found that a possible construction of a non-singular quartic surface in P^3 is to take the intersection of 2 quadrics in P^4..." But that gives a quartic surface in P^4, which typically will be nondegenerate (i.e. not contained in any P^3).

Comment: If you know how to find the ideal of a smooth genus-2 curve of degree 6 in $\mathbf P^3$ the rest should be straightforward to compute: that ideal will contain lots of elements of degree 4, and you can ask e.g. Macaulay 2 to give you a random such element. With probability $1-\epsilon$ the surface defined by such an element will be smooth. (cont'd)

Comment: For any hyperelliptic curve $C$, the "tricanonical" embedding defined by $|3K_C|$ will embed it as a curve of degree 6 in $\mathbf P^4$. Projecting from a general point will then give a smooth curve of genus 2 and degree 6 as required. So the problem now is to compute the ideal of a hyperelliptic curve tricanonically embedded in $\mathbf P^4$. I don't know how to do that right now.